# Flipping a node horizontally

Tags: swift, scenekit

I tried to play with scale values but it was too unreliable. Maybe I was doing something wrong. Is there a way to flip SCNNode horizontally with code?

Comment: Can you be more specific aout the results you get? Is the model visible after flipping the x axis? Do you have the doublesided property set to yes/true on the material for the node? Normally when you flip a model by inverting an axis its normals will be flipped as well.

Answer (score 0):

A scale of x: -1.0, y: 1, z: 1 will mirror the node about the X Axis.  This is they way that you should do it.  Note that if the X Axis is not int he middle of the node, then this is going to change its position.  You can translate it so that the x axis is in the middle then scale it and then translate it back if thats a problem.  Its of course easier just to line up the artwork to begin with so the X axis lies on the plane where you want the mirroring to occur.

Comment: I cannot get the result I want with that code "furniture.scale.x = -furniture.scale.x" What am I doing wrong?